# iPhone : Push Notification settings problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I am using UrbanAirShip Push Notification in my app.

but

I am unable to find my app in iPhone's->settings->Notifications.

I have installed same app in my iPad where it is showing my app in iPad's->Settings->Notifications.

What could be wrong with my iPhone ? or I am missing any steps. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is seen in ipads settings, it should be seen in iPhone settings also, if You have enabled your app for APN properly. You should try like remove that app and its associated provisioning profiles from iPhone, restart it and install again. It might luck.